# Input field required LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, salesforcedx

I need help to put the input field required. When a user click on Search, if the search field is empty, an error message should show in red.

```
<div class="slds-grid">
    <div class="slds-col">
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter id here" required="" value={inputId} onchange={onchangeIdhandler}    class="slds-input" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-col  slds-p-horizontal_large">
        <button class="bg slds-button slds-align_absolute-center"  onclick={handleSearch}>Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add class in input tag like searchTextand then

```
if(!this.template.querySelector('.searchText').value){
    this.template.querySelector('.searchText').setCustomValidity('Enter some text');
    this.template.querySelector('.searchText').reportValidity();
}
else{
    this.template.querySelector('.searchText').setCustomValidity('');
    this.template.querySelector('.searchText').reportValidity();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SLDS, you have to include all the styles and elements yourself. Consider using a `lightning-input` field instead:

```
<lightning-input required label="Search" type="search"></lightning-input>
```